# Git: Finding files where only serialVersionUID changed

Tags: java, git, git-diff

I have a set of auto-generated java files which are checked into git. Each file contains the line

```
final static long serialVersionUID = -4268385597939353497L;
```

where the part after the serialVersionUID is changed to a random number on each regeneration.

Note: This is set in stone and I am aware of "not checking generated code into version control etc.".

How can I identify all files where **only** the serialVersionUID changed?
*Changed* means the files are modified in the working copy, but not committed yet.

My goal is to revert those files via pre-commit hook.

I've come as far as either

```
git diff -U10000 --raw MyFile.java
```

which gives me a diff of the whole file
or

```
git diff -U0 --raw --word-diff=porcelain MyFile.java
```

which gives me a "diff header" plus a list of changes.

Comment: _Changed_ with respect to _what_?  Different branches, different commits, different tags, something else?

Comment: Changed as in "Working copy" vs "Latest commited state on the current branch", i.e. the files are modified, but not committed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this particular StackOverflow answer doesn't solve your problem (I literally *can't* solve it properly as I don't have a Java parser).  It's all about all the *other* stumbling blocks you're going to run into, and how to avoid them so that your task really is only the Java-related part.

It's important here to note that there are *three* copies of every file here:

- the one in your current commit, `HEAD:MyFile.java` (use `git show HEAD:MyFile.java` to see this one);
- the one in your *proposed next commit*, `:MyFile.java` (again, use `git show` to see it); and
- the one in your *work-tree*, `MyFile.java`, which you can see and edit directly.

The `git diff` command will, in general, pick *two of the three* to compare.

Running `git diff` with no arguments, or with arguments that select only a file (not a commit), compares the *index* copy of the file with the *work-tree* copy.  It does not extract the currently-committed file.  The index copy is the one that `git commit` will write to a *new* commit, so it is, in effect, what you are proposing to commit now.

Using `git diff --cached` tells Git to compare the file(s) in `HEAD` to the file(s) in the index.  Using `git diff HEAD` tells Git to compare the file(s) in `HEAD` to the file(s) in the work-tree.  So these are how you select which *pairs* of files get compared.  But no matter what, each `git diff` just picks one *pair* of files, or one set-of-pairs if you let Git compare all the files.

If you run `git commit -a`—and I recommend that you *don't*, here—that's roughly equivalent to `git add -u && git commit`, except that it builds a temporary index with the updated files.  Things get particularly tricky in the various commit hooks here since there are now multiple different index files with different proposed-next-commits.  That's why I recommend avoiding `git commit -a` here.  It's already hard enough to work with, and reason about, *three* copies of a file, and using tricky commit options, such as `-a` or `--only` or `--include` throws a fourth and even sometimes a fifth set of copies into the mix.

(Git can only deal with one index file at a time.  A standard `git commit` has only the one standard index file.  The standard index file has copies of the files that would or will go into the next commit.<sup>1</sup>  The options cause Git to create additional temporary index files, into which it builds the proposed new commit, then run the rest of the operations—including your hooks—with `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` set in the environment to make these sub-commands look at whichever temporary index is to be used.  If all goes well and `git commit` winds up making a new commit, one of these various temporary index files, with whatever contents are appropriate based on the options and arguments, *becomes* the new index, after which you're back to the normal situation with a mere three copies of each file.)

Since your plan is to work in a pre-commit hook, you probably *should* compare the `HEAD` files against the proposed-for-commit files in the index, i.e., you should probably be using `git diff --cached` here.  However, if you intend to do this by *computer program*, rather than as something a human peruses at leisure, you should not be using `git diff` at all.  The front-end `git diff` command is meant for use by *humans*, which is why it paginates and colors the output and does all those kinds of things that just annoy computer programs.  Git calls these fancy front ends *porcelain commands*.

Each kind of `git diff` is implemented by a back-end *plumbing* command.  The plumbing command that compares a commit—technically, a *tree*—to the index is `git diff-index`, which still needs `--cached` to tell it to do the desired comparison: `git diff-index --cached HEAD` produces predictable output, that does not depend on each user's preferred pager, color styles, and so on.

(If you're writing this hook exclusively for your own use, you can use either `git diff` or `git diff-index` since you can compensate for your own personal `git diff` settings.  But it's better, in a sense, to use the plumbing command anyway—then there's no need to compensate for anything.)

Whatever you choose here, you still have to write your own code to interpret the diff output.  You might instead choose to write a program that simply extracts the two files of interest—`HEAD:MyFile.java` and `:MyFile.java`, that is—from the current commit and from the index, and compare them in your own program, rather than using `git diff` at all.  You can extract the files using `git show`, but that has the slight defect that it's another porcelain command.  You can use `git cat-file -p`, which is the underlying plumbing command, to extract the files directly, without going through `git show`.

Actually parsing the Java code would be the most reliable method, so that you don't get tripped up by some sort of silly formatting change.  A more-hacky method such as assuming that everything must match except for one line of some specific form would be not too difficult in, say, awk (read both files one line at a time, check that only one line is different in the two files and that it has the expected form).  All of these seem likely to be simpler than trying to parse diff output, though if you want to parse diff output, a non-Git non-context diff might be simpler.

Finally, regarding:

> My goal is to revert those files via pre-commit hook.

This *is* OK to do (Git will handle it correctly, for some definition of "correct"), but it's also a bit surprising to many Git users.  Git hooks like this are not supposed to *change* things.  The intent of the people writing Git is for Git hooks like this to merely *verify* things.  If something fails the verification step, the hook should exit nonzero, which will cause `git commit` to stop.  Any fixing-up is supposed to be done by some non-hook operation.

Note that `git commit --no-verify` *skips* the pre-commit hook entirely.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, an index has *references to* read-only copies of each file.  Because these copies are read-only, they can be shared.  So "copying" an index is cheap, because it really just copies all the references.  Also, every file that's in the proposed new commit that's 100% bit-for-bit identical to a file that's already in some existing commit, is really just a reference to that file, since every file stored within every commit is itself entirely read-only.

Comment: This is really impressive and a huge insight into git for me, thanks a lot! Using a combination of `git cat-file` and `grep -v "serialVersionUID"` plus the same `grep` for my modified working copy would produce the same files if they differ only by the `serialVersionUID`. Saving those somewhere I can now use the normal `diff` command, check its exit code and I'm done with a single file. I'll need to read this thouroughly and think about how to proceed.